# C# loop through values SQL

Tags: c#, sql, service

We want in our payment application (written in C# will be running as a Windows service) to loop trough a SQL query and check if a reference is filled if the reference is filled the payment status should be checked.

I know how to do this one by one, but we want to perform this once a day (like at night), how can I do this? So I can set our SAP field with the updated payment values.

I want to know how I can loop trough all these values and check them one by one
eg:

```
 K021511 --> K020688 --> K010770 ... and so one

EPN0007901 
Amount in cents:32341 
Order Status:completed
Payment Method:MISTERCASH
```

[image]

If someone can advise me - I have never done this kind of operation before.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start at http://dapper-tutorial.net ... Actually, first just confirm that you know C#... ?

Comment: *"i know how to do this one by one , but we want to perform this once a day"* - It's not clear what exactly the problem is.  So you know how to implement the logic, but you're asking how to schedule it as part of a Windows Service?  Are you familiar with how to write Windows Services?  Have you created any introductory "hello world" services via any tutorials or examples?  Please clarify the problem.

Comment: Hy no the windows service part i got , i know how i can perform this on record at a time but how can i loop trough all of these values and then i can perform my logic on it.

Comment: @AlainSeys: So you're asking how to query a database and loop over the results?  That seems like something which would be covered by tutorials on whatever data access technology you're using.  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: hte query i have , but i want to know how i can let the program go trough a whole list. i have the logic ready for if it is on on one relation. but i want a windows service that checks the whole result list and then execute my payment logic.

so if the list contains 20 results it shoul apply my logic over the 20 result

Comment: @AlainSeys why do you not store the ruslt of the query into a ArrayList and loop afterwards through it? Have you tried something like this?